# Variance of a random variable by matrix

Tags: variance, random-variable, matrix

I'm trying to calculate $ \text{VAR}(\mathbf{XW}) $ where $ \mathbf{X} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2) $ and $\mathbf{X}$ is a matrix of size $ N\times D$ in which all entries are independant so both $ \mu $ and $ \sigma^2 $ are also size $ N\times D$.

$ \mathbf{W} $ is of size $ D \times O $ and it's a deterministic matrix.

So because I didn't know where to start I started with the scalar case:

$$
\text{VAR}(aX) = E[(aX)^2] - E[(aX)]^2 = a^2\mu^2 + a^2\sigma^2 - a^2\mu^2 = a^2\sigma^2
$$

but now I'm having problems extending that to the matrix case because I have

$$
\text{VAR}(\mathbf{XW}) = E[(\mathbf{XW})^2] - E[(\mathbf{XW})]^2
$$
and $ (\mathbf{XW})^2 $ is not a pointwise power

Can someone guide me on which steps to follow? the expected result is a matrix of size $ N \times O$.

For clarification, what I want to compute is the variance of each component of $ \mathbf{XW} $

Comment: If $X$ were a vector, there is a simple well-known formula to produce the covariance of $XW$ in terms of $W$ and $Cov(X)$T To look at Cov of $WX$ for $W$ and $X$ both being matrices, you'd be dealing with a higher order tensor, or you could vec it (stack the columns or rows) and consider the covariance matrix of that vec'd entity (which is a vector after vec;ing).

Comment: @Mark $X$ *is* a vector--it's merely that by convention it is written in a relatively compact form.  Gonzalo, since $XW$ is manifestly a linear combination of the components of $X$, just use the standard rules for computing variances.  If this isn't perfectly clear, write it out in detail for an example using small values of $N,D,O.$  Note that since $XW$ has dimensions $N\times O$, its variance is a matrix of dimensions $NO\times NO,$ not a matrix of size $N\times O.$ Is it possible you just want to compute the variances of the individual components of $XW$?

Comment: @whuber yeah, I want to compute the variance of the individual components

Comment: Please, then, edit your post to make that clear.  Often your notation will be interpreted (as I did) in asking for the variance-covariance matrix of the set of random variables.  I realize the correct interpretation can be inferred by a close reading of your post, but it's best not to leave that to chance.

Comment: @whuber yeah you are right, I will add that for clarification

Comment: Thank you.  Given that component $(i,j)$ of $XW$ is the linear combination $$(XW)_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^D X_{ik}W_{kj},$$ what is the matter with simply applying the usual formula $$\operatorname{Var}((XW)_{ij})=\sum_{k,k^\prime} W_{kj}W_{k^\prime j} \operatorname{Cov}(X_{ik},X_{ik^\prime})?$$

Comment: That seems right, I was confused about how to proceed with matrices